# Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I try to open the code set but it's not open. show below error.How to fix it

Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 because no repositories are defined.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `buildscript` block you have to add the `repositories` also.
Something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have it and I still get the error

Comment: if you find a solution let me konw.

Comment: @tudorprodan any solution you found?